# WooCommerce code - Dynamically add a surcharge to cart and checkout

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've added 2 radio buttons to my WooCommerce cart.  However I want to add a surcharge when one is slected but not the other, and I want it to update the check out data that is displayed.

I know I can do this to add the surcharge all time:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','woocommerce_custom_surcharge' );

function woocommerce_custom_surcharge() {
  global $woocommerce;

    $surcharge = 5.32; 
    $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Surcharge', $surcharge, true, '' );

}
```

however how to I control it to add this or not based on which radio button I have selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I solved this by creating an AJAX to handle the buttons and then in the PHP callback issuing a WC->session->set to set a session variable.  Upon return, I then issue a location.reload() which refreshes the page but does not clear the cache.  That way when the functions.php are loaded again, inside the surcharge function I added as a action_add, I can query the session variable to see which of the radio buttons were clicked and add the appropriate cart->add_fee.

Comment: Let me look back at it.. that was 5 yrs ago :)

Answer (score 1):

The best way is with ajax (untested code):

```
<input type="radio" name"surcharge" value="5.32" class="surcharge" />
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () { 
  $(".surcharge").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "where_is_your.php", // Name of PHP script
        type: "POST",
        data: { 
          action: $(this).val(), //here you get the value 5.32
        }
      }).done(function(data) {
        alert( data.message ); //your success message if you want it
      });
  })
 })
</script>
```

and your php:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','woocommerce_custom_surcharge' );
$surcharge = $_POST['action']; 
function woocommerce_custom_surcharge() {
  global $woocommerce;
    $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Surcharge', $surcharge, true, '' );
}
```

Comment: This is close to what I'm looking for. I want to add the surcharge when Radio Button A is pressed but hide and not add the surcharge when Radio Button B is pressed. The radio buttons are being added in the Themes functions.php code

`add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'hear_about_us_field_update_order_meta' );`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
/**
 * WooCommerce Extra Feature
 * --------------------------
 *
 * Add custom fee to cart automatically
 *
 */
function woo_add_cart_fee() {

  global $woocommerce;

  $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( __('Custom', 'woocommerce'), 5 );

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'woo_add_cart_fee' ); ?>
```

You can use "woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees" to add surcharge money with an amount to your theme, and plus AJAX as above will help you out.

Comment: Thanks.  I know about add_fee, I'm already using that. The issue is that I have to change the add_fee amount based on the radio button that is selected If "A" is selected its one fee, if "B" its another.

Comment: So after I call add_fee, how do I get the cart to refresh with the added fee?

Comment: My logic is: You have to listen, using onchange jquery, if there's select (change) on radio with id and value, and then, you will run ajax function to add fees with the function above, it wouldnt reload the page mate